# Cocos2d. Digital joystick (joypad)?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, joystick, joypad

There are a lot of examples of analog joypad for cocos2d. But I need a simple 8-directional (8-positional) digital one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SneakyInput](https://github.com/sneakyness/SneakyInput) for cocos2D, which has both analog and D-pad implementations. If you happen to be using it already, simply set the following properties for a digital implementation:

```
    joystick.isDPad = YES;
    joystick.numberofDirections = 8; //8-directional
```

Comment: thanks. It wasn't workable because of warnings which appear after cocos2d project creation

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://zaldzbugz.posterous.com/first-article

It's a simple joystick for cocos2D, maybe it could help you.

Comment: that link is a tutorial on how to use it. You can use this github link to directly download the source: https://github.com/zaldzbugz/ZJoystick