# How to use a library with Cocos2D

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to use this library [Here](https://github.com/sneakyness/SneakyInput)

But i am not sure how i integrate this with cocos2D.

Could some tell me how?

I am trying to follow this answer:

[Cocos2d. Digital joystick (joypad)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734793/cocos2d-digital-joystick-joypad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [This](http://www.qcmat.com/sneakyinput-joystick-dpad-and-buttons-for-cocos2d/). On the link hopefully you will find the necessary Usage on detail.